# How can I execute a Java method more than once?

Tags: java, loops

I need to run my/an Objects method a second time. Is this allowed? How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean restarting a method? as in, calling the method again?

Comment: To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.

Comment: If you're looking at recursion, as outlined below, make sure you have a way of breaking out of it, as recursion is a lovely way to cause a hard crash.

Comment: yes as I may have a continuos loop due to randomly generating numbers, of which I wont be able to get out of so I want to rerun the method again in the case that this happens

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that this doesn't 'restart' a method.  Once your recursive methods return, the remaining code in the method will run.

Comment: if this is a loop, just use `continue;` to move on to the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: @bob - if your program is in an infinite loop, you won't be *able* to break out of it, and in any case the proper fix is to rewrite the method so that it will always terminate.  (If it doesn't, and you "restart" it, who's to say it won't get stuck in the loop again?)

Comment: no i dont want it to continue once the recursive methods have finished, I will have to find another way

Comment: okay thanks for your help but im am going to refactor it somehow

Comment: Consider creating a small example of the problem you actually have.

Comment: Since you're new here, one suggestion is to ask the question you did (above), but also explain what you are trying to do a bit more so we can give you even better answers.  (Also, tell us what you have already tried - you typically get better responses if you can show you aren't just trying to freeload.)  I hope that helps!  Welcome to SO.

Comment: There's nothing in this question that indicates that it's asking about recursion. The answer should either explain the new-fangled "for-loop" that everyone's raving about, or the question should be clarified ... :)

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but you can simply call a method from itself (it's called  [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)):

```
void recursiveMethod() {
    System.out.println("Called the recursive method");
    recursiveMethod();
}
```

Calling that method will print the line "Called the recursive method" until you get a StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the method again from inside itself (AKA recursion).  So, something like this:

```
public void myMethod() {
  // Do some stuff here.

  // Possible conditional statement...
  if(restart) {
    myMethod();  // This will "restart" the method.
  }
}
```

If you have a more specific example that you're thinking of, that may help improve your question.

Comment: I would think a do-while/for(;;) loop would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

recursion? of course java supports it

```
public int foo (int param) {
   if (param == 0)
       return 0;
   return param + foo (--param);
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
   System.out.println (foo (5));
}
```

Comment: The technical name for this implementation is "Infinite Recursion", I believe. ;)

Comment: this recursion example will cause an infinite loop

Comment: It also won't compile due to foo is not static :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you have a reference to the object (you already ran the method),
Simply repeat the previous statement:

```
myDog.bark(); // bark once
myDog.bark(); // bark again
```